# Getting the data from 2d python chart

Tags: python, plot, 2d

The topic title might be a bit bad, I apologize for that.
Here is a 2d chart I have:
[image]

What I would like to get is for defined "Year" `(x axis)` and defined "number of pieces" `(y axis)` values, to get the area to which the red point would belong (in this case "C").
Basically I would like to somehow replicate this plot to python, and then read the specific areas to which points belong (for give "Year" and "number of pieces" data).

Is something like this possible without installing some additional python plot modules?
The plot is an image .gif file.

EDIT: I do not want to import this .gif plot to python and then read particular pixel from it (so no, not image processing). I would just like to somehow recreate it in python, even if that would mean generating a long list of tens of values.

Comment: what's the format of the plot you have ???

Comment: this is image processing ! are you want to extract the values from image?

Comment: Yes. So how would I do this in python? Generate some long list of values, then interpolate somehow between those values?

Comment: @user3137724 So, you want someone to do your homework   :)   you haven't tried anything yet ??

Comment: No, I want somebody to tell me how this could be done. I am a python beginner, and not a programmer.

Comment: you must use an image processing lib for this aim ! i suggest use `Opencv` its most powerful and popular ! http://docs.opencv.org/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html

Comment: are u interested only in THIS PRECISE data sample ?? It could be imported as lists...

Comment: This is only an example not a precise data sample. But if you could show me how to do it with this simple example, I could replicate it with the real one. How can it be imported as lists?

Comment: The only way I can think of, to be fair, is manual data entry... what do you think ?

Comment: I do not know, that's why I asked.
Would you be so kind to write down at least the starting few values of that manual entry? Thank you.

Comment: give me few minutes please.. I'll write an example

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, Fell asleep while coding...
Check below if it works for you

```
graph = [
            [1998.4, 1998.5, 1998.7, 1999.2, 1999.8, 2001.1],
            [1999.8, 2000.0, 2000.5, 2000.9, 2001.6, 2003.0],
            [2001.1, 2001.3, 2001.7, 2002.1, 2002.8, 2004.1],
            [2002.3, 2002.7, 2003.1, 2003.5, 2004.0, 2004.9],
            [2003.8, 2003.8, 2004.0, 2004.2, 2004.5, 2005.0]
        ]
MyStop = False

def interPolate(x0, y0, x1, y1, x):
        if x1 == x0:
                return y0
        else:
                return y0 + (y1-y0)*(x-x0)/(x1-x0)

while not MyStop:
        nop = raw_input("Input the number of pieces [0 to 5,000] (x to stop): ")
        if nop <> "x":
                if nop.isdigit():
                        inop = int(nop)
                        if inop <= 5000 and inop >= 0:
                                y = raw_input("Input the year: ")
                                if y.isdigit():
                                        yy = int(y)
                                        val = []
                                        for aList in graph:
                                                for j in range(len(aList)-1):
                                                        if 1000*j <= inop and 1000*(j+1) > inop:
                                                                val.append(interPolate(1000*j, aList[j], 1000*(j+1),aList[j+1],inop))
                                        if yy > val[4]:
                                                print "Value in Region : F."
                                        elif yy > val[3]:
                                                print "Value in Region : E."
                                        elif yy > val[2]:
                                                print "Value in Region : D."
                                        elif yy > val[1]:
                                                print "Value in Region : C."
                                        elif yy > val[0]:
                                                print "Value in Region : B."
                                        else:
                                                print "Value in Region : A."
                                else:
                                        print "Something Went Wrong !! :("
        else:
                print "Will Exit Now! ByeBye."
                MyStop = True
```

Comment: Thank you very much @mlwn. But what do the decimal places after the year (example: 1998.4 - 4 in this case) represent?

Comment: I was just trying to simulate the graph... 1998.4 will match the point 0 of curve A... then 1998.5 will match the point 1000 in curve A ... etc.. did you get my point ?

Comment: No, sorry I didn't understand it. Could you explain it a bit more please? Sorry for bothering you.
Thank you.

Comment: First of all, I am sorry for the typo in the first line, I've already fixed it from 1998.8 to 1999.8. Secondly, all those values are approximate as I  didn't spend time to exactly measure the coordinates. I have modified the image you have sent in order to explain what i mean. This is basic math-graph. I am trying to get the coordinates of the values (0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, and 5000) which are easy numbers... if each graph is a function f(), f(x) will be the straight line. Please check the image on the link http://i60.tinypic.com/xax7ys.gif

Comment: In my picture, I only prepared for Graph A... the same applies for the remaining graphs.. then you can build the graph list_of_lists (or matrix)